# How to pass data from Fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm new at Android. I want to pass data from a fragment to another Activity. This fragment is displayed on `MainActivity` and I need to pass data to  `DetalleActividadActivity`.

This is my fragment's code:

```
public final static String EXTRA_PARAMETER = "com.example.arc3labswtm_android.customs.PARAMETER";


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 


    mAdapter = new ActivitiesAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.act_itemlist);
      ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.activities_fragment_list);
      listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      listViewToDo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
            {

                final Activities currentItem = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                String pid = currentItem.getId();
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetalleActividadActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                newActivity.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAMETER, pid);
            }
        });
      refreshItemsFromTable();
}
```

This is my Activity's code:

```
public class DetalleActividadActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_detalle_actividad);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String parameter = intent.getStringExtra(ActivitiesFragment.EXTRA_PARAMETER);


    }
}
```

Any ideas? I don't know if this has something to do but my Activities are in this package: 
`com.example.arc3labswtm_android`

And my fragment is in this: 
`com.example.arc3labswtm_android.customs`

I don't know if that is why `EXTRA_PARAMETER` does not work.

When I get to the DetalleActividadActivity the `parameter` is always  null.

Please help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is , you have put the EXTRA_PARAMETER to the `IntentExtras` after the `Activity start`

You need to put the Extras to the intent before you start the activity.

You can pass the data through intent when you start the Activity from Fragment like this

```
 Intent newActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), DetalleActividadActivity.class);
 newActivity.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAMETER, pid);
 startActivity(newActivity);
```

When the Activity is Created , you can retrieve the data like this

```
 String parameter = getIntent().getStringExtra(ActivitiesFragment.EXTRA_PARAMETER);
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was the problem hehehe, Thanks @Libin